# How to add script files in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

The following code normally pops up the modal in bootsrap. But when I add it to angular 6 component.html it won't work. I tried it putting inside the init(){} but it also gives an error. How to resolve this issue?

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function bookedModal(){
      $("#bookedModal").modal("show");
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: When I add it ro the component.html nothing happens. Once I add it to init $ is not detected

Comment: Add `declare let $:any;` to the top of your component file. But you should really be using something like ng-bootstrap, which does  not require jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. I think i'll look into ng-bootsrap